# Testing ZK applications with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, zk

I've recently started working on Selenium Webdriver (Chrome) for Java language. My application is developed using zk framework, hence its ID's are randomly generated. Eg:

```
/div[@id='z_j0_7!cave']/form[@id='loginForm']/table[@id='z_j0_9']/tbody/tr[@id='z_j0_a!chdextr']/td/table[@id='z_j0_a']/tbody/tr[@id='z_j0_a!cave']/td[@id='z_j0_c!chdextr']/input[@id='z_j0_c']
```

How can I find xpath of such elements?

The zul file is like this:

```
<h:form id="loginForm" action="j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
  <vbox sclass="login_grid z-grid" spacing="2px">
    <hbox widths="7em, 8em">
      <label value="${c:l('login')}:"/>
      <textbox  id="login"  name="j_username" value="${LoginForm.login}"       use="de.hybris.platform.cscockpit.components.login.LoginTextBox"/>
    </hbox>
    <hbox widths="7em, 8em">
      <label value="${c:l('password')}:"/> 
      <textbox  type="password" id="pw" name="j_password"  value="${LoginForm.password}"  use="de.hybris.platform.cscockpit.components.login.PasswordTextBox"/>
    </hbox>
  </vbox>       
</h:form>
```

View as in developer mode: (For label user id and its input field)

```
<table id="z_38_a" z.type="zul.box.Box" class="z-hbox" z.zcls="z-hbox" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="z_38_a!cave" valign="top">
        <td id="z_38_b!chdextr" z.coexist="true" align="left" style="width:7em">        <span id="z_38_b" class="z-label" z.zcls="z-label">ユーザー ID:</span>
        </td>
        <td id="z_38_b!chdextr2" class="z-hbox-sep">
        </td>
        <td id="z_38_c!chdextr" z.coexist="true" align="left" style="width:8em"> <input id="z_38_c" z.type="zul.vd.Txbox" class="z-textbox" z.zcls="z-textbox" type="text" name="j_username" value="admin">
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you share relevant HTML as well??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur.. I have updated the question.

Comment: And let me know which element do you want to locate?? Because I couldn't see any table HTML here.. and also mention your programming language..

Comment: The page is created by zk hence instead of pure html, it has zul tags as shown in the question. I'm looking for the xpath of login and password input fields. I can paste the view as I see in firepath or developer mode.

Comment: Programming language is java and I using Chromedriver.

Comment: ZK has a static id generator from zk 7 and above what you van use when testing.

Comment: @chillworld.. I'm using the zk framework integrated in hybris tool and the hybris version I'm working on supports 3.6.4 version of zk. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm looking for the xpath of login and password input fields.
>   Programming language is java and I using Chromedriver.

There is no need to do extra stuff and  use `xpath` to locate desire element, you can use [`By.name()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#name-java.lang.String-) locator to locate easily desire element as well as below :-

```
WebElement user = driver.findElement(By.name("j_username"));

WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("j_password"));
```

Comment: Thanks Saurabh! I tried this way initially, but that time may be there was something wrong that the value was not getting entered automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I have found when working with the ZK framework, the best source for finding paths is using the Katalon Recorder. This gives multiple options to use for each element. Example:

```
for login
name=j_username
xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text())and normalize-space(.)='User ID;'])[1]/following::input[1]
xpath=//input
```